Why does the simulation graph changing when I change the step size?
I encounter some problems when I simulate the diff model as a fixed-step solution.
When I changed the step size, my simulation data is changing.
Step-size 0.1:

step-size 0.01:

What should I do to make it right?
Thank you in advance for your help.
if I'm using values for step-size smaller than 0.01 ( like 0.02 0.0001) ,it works good.but i cant use 0.2 0.5 or 1,2 etc.
The variable step solutions working like step-size 0.001 or smaller.
function [ddZs,ddZu] = fcn(dZs,dZu,Zs,Zu,Zr,Fa,ms,bs,ks,mu,kt,fc,fm,vs,sigma,t)
%% System parameters
% ms=210;
% bs=210;
% ks=210;
% mu=18;
% kt=800;
% fc=60;
% fm=116;
% vs=1;
% sigma=1;

Ff=fc*sign(dZu-dZs)*(fm-fc)*exp(-((dZu-dZs)/vs)^2)*sign(dZu-dZs)+sigma*(dZu-dZs);%Stribeck friction modelling

ddZs=(-ks/ms)*Zs + (ks/ms)*Zu + (-bs/ms)*dZs + (bs/ms)*dZu + (1/ms)*Fa + (Ff/ms);

ddZu=(ks/mu)*(Zs-Zu) + (bs/mu)*(dZs-dZu)-(Fa/mu)-(Ff/mu)-(kt/mu)*(Zu-Zr);


end



You've provided no information at all about what you simulation is doing, what blocks you're using, or how that signal is being generated. Presumably there's something time-dependent in your model (like an integrator or a signal generator) but we can only speculate. Please [edit] your question to make it answerable...

I added something now,I hope this is enough for now.

Did you check the sample time information? Have a look here if you're not familiar with this option => Simulink Help
